# Detect click on div background 30% resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` with background 30% resized and a `img` sized 100%
[image]

I would like detect `onclick` only on the background resized div (purple in the picture below), not on all element

What is the best way?

Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="div1" style="width:600px; background:url(img/litlePict.png) no-repeat scroll center center / 30% auto">
    <img class="store" src="img/mypict.png" width="100%" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is what i would like do!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the best way is to add a div in the .div1

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do that. Why not set your background image to 100% and your img to 30%? You would be able to catch a click on it alot easier. Otherwise you could create a blank div that's positioned on top of the image that matches the size of the background image and have a click listener on it.

Comment: It's unclear to me how the background is visible behind the image. Is the latter transparent?

Comment: How is the background image getting in front of the image inside of it?

Comment: yes, i have a img with transparence. @DarrenGourley I use that because with animate the img not follow the div

Comment: Put the small div in front of the large div and make it transparent. This will allow for a smaller clickable area in the large img.

Comment: @BillCriswell the background image is always visible, never hidden. The img fadeIn when i click on the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test this code, but it might give you a hint on how to achieve something like this!

```
$('.element').on('click', function (e) {
    var xPossition = $(this).position().left; // The distance between 'zero' and the left of the element on the X Axis
    var yPossition = $(this).position().top;  // The distance between 'zero' and the top of the element on the Y Axis
    var elemWidth  = $(this).width(); // The height of the element
    var elemHeight = $(this).height(); // The widthof the element

    var mouseX = e.pageX - xPossition; // The possition of the mouse on the X Axis of the screen removing the distance to the LEFT of the element clicked
    var mouseY = e.pageY - yPossition; // The possition of the mouse on the Y Axis of the screen removing the distance to the TOP of the element clicked

    // Check if the position of the mouse relative to the element is between the first 35% and the last 35% of the width and height of the element
    if ( (mouseX > elemWidth*0.35 && mouseX < elemWidth - elemWidth*0.35) && (mouseY > elemHeight*0.35 && mouseY < elemHeight - elemHeight*0.35) ) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a little changed your code but work fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to do so with so few HTML tags. You should rather get another div in the div1, and then play with z-index and event propagation.

Comment: ok but the first div image is png format with trasparence and when i do rgba(0,0,0,1) the background is black. how i can make opacity in the first this whitout impute on the second div?

Comment: Hi P. Frank, can you elaborate on exactly what you are trying to accomplish? What's the purpose of the top image, is it always transparent or are you animating its opacity with javascript thru interaction? and why is the smaller div being applied as a backgroundImage and not just simply another div, is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this computationally, getting the `background-size` dynamically and then applying it to the `div`. The contents of the div don't really matter in this case, so I left out the image.

```js
// Get all the elements and apply the following code using an array forEach
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bg-click')).forEach(function(a){
  var bgsize = parseInt(a.style.backgroundSize, 10) / 100;
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    // Get the current width and height (expected value in pixels)
    var w = parseInt(a.style.width, 10);
    var h = parseInt(a.style.height, 10);
    // If the x click is outside of the center, or the y click is
    // use preventDefault to stop the click.
    if(
      e.layerX < w / 2 - w * (bgsize / 2) 
      || e.layerX > w / 2 + w * (bgsize / 2)
      || e.layerY < h / 2 - h * (bgsize / 2) 
      || e.layerY > h / 2 + h * (bgsize / 2)
    ){
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
    // Otherwise, execute this
      console.log('clicked in center');
      alert('clicked in center');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="bg-click" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200) 50% 50% no-repeat; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-size: 30% 30%;"></div>
```

Since you background isn't actually an element, you have to do the computation yourself, so why not try it with an actual element:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bg')).forEach(function(a){
  a.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    alert('clicked');
  })
})
```

```css
.bg-holder {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.bg-holder .bg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%%;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-holder">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer but when i animate the div your function not worknig. And on your example when you click right the square no alert appear

Comment: There are downsides to this, as there are a lot more catches if you have dynamic positioning (mostly having to do with offsets). Also, be aware that alerts do not appear in Chrome because of sandboxing (they do in Safari, but thats why the console.log is in there)

Comment: ok your first code not working for me. for example my div is animate width:0 to width:1000 but when i test your code it's the same result. he click on all element.

Comment: @P.Frank I am very sorry that the implementation to this specific case does not apply to all the things someone might want to do with it, but that's not what I am here for. The second code is _better_, the first is an illustration of how you _potentially_ could do this with javascript.

Comment: @P.Frank Thanks for the down vote - the first code _is working_ it is just not working _with your modifications_, but hey, there are probably no _worse_ answers on this page.

Comment: @P.Frank excuse my snippiness then :) Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Put another div within the div1. Size and position this inner div in the place you want.

It will be transparent so the appearance won't be bothered. You can use 'onClick' on this div instead.

Comment: ok but the first div image is png format with trasparence and when i do rgba(0,0,0,1) the background is black. how i can make opacity in the first this whitout impute on the second div?

Comment: @P.Frank When you use RGBA, the 'A' should be 0 for it to become transparent. If you set it to '1', it will be opaque! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the underlying `div` is present in position you clicked on,

try this:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('click',function(e){
     // on top layer
     e.target.style.pointerEvents = "none";

     var under = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    
     if (under === div)
      under.style.background='blue';
   
      //restore pointer-events
      e.target.style.pointerEvents = "visiblePainted";

   });
```

```css
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
img{
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    background:rgba(0,225,0,0.3)
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="store" src="img/mypict.png" width="100%" />
</div>
```

in this scenario you entire background div will be resized not background-image like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, revising my answer after reading your update.

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="con" style="position:relative; width:60px; height:60px; background-color: #ff0000;">
            <div id="smallerDiv" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px;  width:20px; height:20px; background-color: #ededed;">              
            </div>
            <img id="theImg" src="imgs/topImg.png" style="opacity:0; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; pointer-events:none;"/>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>

        $("#con").animate({"width":"600px","height":"600px"}, 1000);
        $("#smallerDiv").animate({"width":"200px","height":"200px","top":"200px",'left':"200px"}, 1000);

        document.getElementById("smallerDiv").onclick = function(){
            $("#theImg").animate({"opacity":1}, 500);
        };

    </script>
</html>
```

This will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onclick(
   function(e){ 
       e.stopImmediatePropogation(); 
       // do other stuff
   });
```

Comment: This is a badly written answer and probably incorrect

Comment: not working. I want click on the div backround image